# Save and update on same xhtml is not working in primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Hi i tried the following functionality using primefaces.
In my xhtml i have a input field which takes input and saves into db.After completion of save i display the saved data in data table of primefaces.
Upto now works fine.now i add single selection to datatable .when user click on the row i update the same input column with selected data.
For this i use the following code

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:growl id="messages" />
    <p:panel id="panel" header="Currency">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="currencyGrid">
            <p:outputLabel value="Currency :"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{currencyBean.currencyMaster.currDesc}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{currencyBean.saveCurrency}"
                         update="currencytable">
        </p:commandButton>

        <p:dataTable id="currencytable" var="cur" 
                     value="#{currencyBean.currencyList}" widgetVar="dlg"
                     selection="#{currencyBean.currencyMaster}" 
                     selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{cur.currId}">
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{currencyBean.onRowSelect}"
                    update=":form:currencyGrid" />
            <p:column headerText="ID" style="font-size:12px;">
                <h:outputText value="#{cur.currId}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Description" style="font-size:12px;">
                <h:outputText value="#{cur.currDesc}" />
            </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

And My Bean code is:

```
@managedBean
@viewScoped
@component 
public class CurrencyBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    private CurrencyMaster currencyMaster;

    private List<CurrencyMaster> currencyList;

    public CurrencyMaster getCurrencyMaster() {
        return currencyMaster;
    }

    public void setCurrencyMaster(CurrencyMaster currencyMaster) {
        this.currencyMaster = currencyMaster;
    }           
    public void saveCurrency(){
        try{
            currencyService.saveCurrency(currencyMaster);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void currencyList(){
        setCurrencyList(currencyService.getCurrencyList());
    }
    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {}            
    public void onRowUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {}
}
```

So when i click on currrencytable row the input field populated properly and update operation also.

The problem is when i directly enter the data into input column my globalMaster property is going to be null.

And the following error is occured;

attempt to create saveOrUpdate event with null entity

I change the scopes of the bean but i did not find the solution.

And i find more solutions for the above exception but my problem is the new values are does not set to currencymaster.

Is there any mistake i done in this context.please guide me..

Comment: What package is ViewScoped from? Also the annotations are capitalized. Are you using spring too?

Comment: Thank you for the response.javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped,javax.annotation.ManagedBean and i used Spring also.

Comment: change the import package of your managed bean to this `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`

Comment: Sorry i changed javax.annotation.ManagedBean to javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean but not working